# Adding Supplemental Documents. Create link to other document using viewTabs

Tags: docusignapi

How can i add Supplemental Documents in main documents for user to view.

I found viewTabs but could not find how to use in using Rest API call.

I tried docuSign RestAPI explorer but no luck. Can you please let me know which tabs need to add it.

Regards,
Dishant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [supplemental documents documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/documents#supplemental-documents). In short, you can add the fields

- `includeInDownload` -- Determines whether the supplemental document is included in the combined document download.
- `display` --  Specifies whether the supplemental document is displayed in a modal dialog, inline, or as downloadable.
- `signerMustAcknowledge` --    Specifies whether the signer must acknowledge the receipt of the supplemental document if the signer does not have Approve and View tabs.

at the `document` level or use the `Approve Tab` and/or `View tab` at the recipient level.

### Account-level permissions

You must also set your account to enable the supplemental document features. See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54714676/64904) answer for more info.