# Demo Account issue: Account does not have permission to set 'display' or 'signermustacknowledge' properties on document

Tags: docusignapi

We are creating Docusign integration and want to add supplemental document to our DocuSign envelopes request. Could not find how to do it in Rest API Explorer. When I create manual Json on our Demo account with signermustacknowledege and display i get following response back.

> This Account lacks sufficient permissions. Account does not have permission to >set 'display' or 'signermustacknowledge' properties on document

Can you please let me know where i can find API documentation for it and how can I test it as i don't have permission.

Regards,
Dishant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely be able to enable that yourself by logging into the web console and navigating to Go to Admin > Signing Settings > Supplemental Documents.

If you are using a custom permission set, ensure you have the 'Sender can override' boxes checked for the options you would like to use.

If you've checked both and still get the error, or if the options are hidden, open a case with [DocuSign Support](https://support.docusign.com) and provide your Demo account number.